# Get the next file name to upload

Tags: asp.net, file, file-upload, if-statement

I have the following C# code (which is about uploading files to the server)

```
for (int i = 0; i < Request.Files.Count-1; i++)
                {
                    if (Request.ContentLength != 0)
                    {
                        int Size = Request.Files[i].ContentLength / 1024;
                        if (Size <= 512)
                        {
                            string LocalFile = Request.Files[i].FileName;
                            int dot = LocalFile.LastIndexOf('.');
                            string FileType = LocalFile.Substring(dot + 1);
                            if (FileType == "gif" || FileType == "jpg" || FileType == "png" || FileType == "GIF" || FileType == "JPG" || FileType == "PNG")
                            {
                                int LastIndex = LocalFile.LastIndexOf(@"\") + 1;
                                string File = LocalFile.Substring(LastIndex, LocalFile.Length - LastIndex);
                                string Path = Server.MapPath(" ../images/tracks") + "..\\" + File;
                                Request.Files[i].SaveAs(Path);
                                if (i != Request.Files.Count - 1)
                                    ImageList += string.Format("images/tracks/{0}|", File);
                                else { ImageList += string.Format("images/tracks/{0}", File); }
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Response.Write("The file is too big !");
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Response.Write("Unknown Error !");
                    }
                }
```

The problem is that there is more than one file upload field.

I want to creat condition, that will check if there is file after file[i] (chack if file[i+1] empty)
if yes the program will do this code: `ImageList += string.Format("images/tracks/{0}", File);`

else: `ImageList += string.Format("images/tracks/{0}|", File);`

My question is how the condition should be look like?

Whish for help, thanks!

Comment: You shouldn't need to perform a check for the one after as you are looping through the full length of files already `for (int i = 0; i < Request.Files.Count-1; i++)` - or am i misunderstanding the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove your condition(If) and add all strings with Ending character. at the end of loop, you can remove the last character, if it is "|".

On your code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < Request.Files.Count-1; i++)
            {
                if (Request.ContentLength != 0)
                {
                    int Size = Request.Files[i].ContentLength / 1024;
                    if (Size <= 512)
                    {
                        string LocalFile = Request.Files[i].FileName;
                        int dot = LocalFile.LastIndexOf('.');
                        string FileType = LocalFile.Substring(dot + 1);
                        if (FileType == "gif" || FileType == "jpg" || FileType == "png" || FileType == "GIF" || FileType == "JPG" || FileType == "PNG")
                        {
                            int LastIndex = LocalFile.LastIndexOf(@"\") + 1;
                            string File = LocalFile.Substring(LastIndex, LocalFile.Length - LastIndex);
                            string Path = Server.MapPath(" ../images/tracks") + "..\\" + File;
                            Request.Files[i].SaveAs(Path);
                            //if (i != Request.Files.Count - 1)
                                ImageList += string.Format("images/tracks/{0}|", File);
                            //else { ImageList += string.Format("images/tracks/{0}", File); }
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Response.Write("The file is too big !");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Response.Write("Unknown Error !");
                }
            }
           //Remove the last character
           if (ImageList.EndsWith("|")) ImageList = ImageList.Remove(ImageList.Length - 1, 1);
}
```